# Huffman decoding EOF character hitting NullPointerException

Tags: java, project, decoding, compression, huffman-code

Hi I am working on decoding a file compressed using huffman encoding. We are using `EOF` characters to indicate we are done with decompressing. Whenever I code for an `EOF` characters I hit a `NullPointerException`. It works fine when I do not include the check for it but I end up with the `EOF` character. I do not understand how I am getting the `NullPointerException` and I would appreciate anyone who could help. Thank you

```
public static void decompress(String in, String out)
{
    try 
    {   
        String result = "";
        BinaryNode<Character> pointer = huffTree;
        ArrayList<Character> a = new ArrayList<Character>();
        File outFile = new File(out);
        FileOutputStream decompressedFile = new FileOutputStream(outFile);

        for(char c : decodings.toString().toCharArray())
        {
            if(c == '0')
            {
                pointer = pointer.getLeft();
            }
            else if(c == '1')
            {
                pointer = pointer.getRight();
            }
            if(pointer.isLeaf())
            {
                if(pointer.getElement() == '^')
                {
                    return;
                }
                 decompressedFile.write(pointer.getElement());
                pointer = huffTree;
            }
        }
        decompressedFile.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println("Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the null pointer exception happening? (according to the stack trace)

Comment: On the line with `if(pointer.getElement() == '^')`

Comment: What is BinaryNode? I'm just guessing but I think `pointer.getElement() == '^'` is redundant because you are only in that block if `pointer.getElement() != '^'`. Also most likely you have an issue without `pointer.getElemnt()` returning `null` is it?

Comment: Whoops yes you're right. Without the `pointer.getElement() != '^'` I do not get the `NullPointerException` but it still does not ignore the EOF character...

Comment: Where are you checking for EOF?

Comment: Sorry the `^` is supposed to indicate EOF character

Comment: Why are you looking for the EOF character in your Huffman tree? Shouldn't it compare c == '^' instead?